# Implementation of Simpson's Rule (SICP Exercise 1.29)

Tags: algorithm, lisp, scheme, racket, sicp

Following is my code for [SICP exercise 1.29](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html). The exercise asks us to implement
Simpson's Rule using higher order procedure `sum`. It's supposed to be more
accurate than the original `integral` procedure. But I don't know why it's not
the case in my code:

```
(define (simpson-integral f a b n)
  (define h (/ (- b a) n))
  (define (next x) (+ x (* 2 h)))
  (* (/ h 3) (+ (f a)
                (* 4 (sum f (+ a h) next (- b h)))
                (* 2 (sum f (+ a (* 2 h)) next (- b (* 2 h))))
                (f b))))
```

Some explanations of my code: As

```
h/3 * (y_{0} + 4*y_{1} + 2*y_{2} + 4*y_{3} + 2*y_{4} + ... + 2*y_{n-2} + 4*y_{n-1} + y_{n})
```

equals

```
h/3 * (y_{0}
       + 4 * (y_{1} + y_{3} + ... + y_{n-1})
       + 2 * (y_{2} + y_{4} + ... + y_{n-2})
       + y_{n})
```

I just use `sum` to compute `y_{1} + y_{3} + ... + y_{n-1}` and `y_{2} +
y_{4} + ... + y_{n-2}`.

Complete code here:

```
#lang racket

(define (cube x) (* x x x))

(define (sum term a next b)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (+ (term a)
         (sum term (next a) next b))))

(define (integral f a b dx)
  (define (add-dx x) (+ x dx))
  (* (sum f (+ a (/ dx 2.0)) add-dx b)
     dx))

(define (simpson-integral f a b n)
  (define h (/ (- b a) n))
  (define (next x) (+ x (* 2 h)))
  (* (/ h 3) (+ (f a)
                (* 4 (sum f (+ a h) next (- b h)))
                (* 2 (sum f (+ a (* 2 h)) next (- b (* 2 h))))
                (f b))))
```

Some tests(The exact value should be 0.25):

```
> (integral cube 0 1 0.01)
0.24998750000000042
> (integral cube 0 1 0.001)
0.249999875000001

> (simpson-integral cube 0 1.0 100)
0.23078806666666699
> (simpson-integral cube 0 1.0 1000)
0.24800798800666748
> (simpson-integral cube 0 1.0 10000)
0.2499999999999509
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution the x-values are computed as follows:

```
h = (b-a)/n
x1 = a+1
x3 = x1 +2*h
x5 = x3 +2*h
...
```

This means rounding errors slowly accumulate.
It happens when `(b-a)/n` is not representable as floating point.

If we instead compute `xi` as `a+ (i*(b-a))/n` you will get more accurate results.

This variant of your solution uses the above method to compute the `xi`.

```
(define (simpson-integral3 f a b n)
  (define h (/ (- b a) n))
  (define (next i) (+ i 2))
  (define (f* i) (f (+ a (/ (* i (- b a)) n))))
  (* (/ h 3)
     (+ (f a)
        (* 4 (sum f* 1 next n))
        (* 2 (sum f* 2 next (- n 1)))
        (f b))))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in how you're constructing the terms, the way you're alternating between even terms (multiplied by `2`) and odd terms (multiplied by `4`) is not correct. I solved this problem by passing an additional parameter to `sum` to keep track of the current term's even-or-odd nature, there are other ways but this worked for me, and the accuracy got improved:

```
(define (sum term a next b i)
  (if (> a b)
      0
      (+ (term a i)
         (sum term (next a) next b (+ i 1)))))

(define (simpson-integral f a b n)
  (let* ((h (/ (- b a) n))
         (term (lambda (x i)
                 (if (even? i)
                     (* 2.0 (f x))
                     (* 4.0 (f x)))))
         (next (lambda (x) (+ x h))))
    (* (+ (f a)
          (sum term a next b 1)
          (f b))
       (/ h 3.0))))

(simpson-integral cube 0 1 1000)
=> 0.2510004999999994
```

Comment: Thank you Óscar. But could you please tell me where I'm wrong? I couldn't figure it out myself. And I added a test case of `(simpson-integral cube 0 1.0 10000)` to show that my code seems to be converging on 0.25. Just not so fast as the original one.

Comment: @Chenggang You're generating two series (`sum` is being called twice), when the right thing would be to have one series with alternating 4,2 factors

Comment: Chenggang is just reordering the terms.